# How do I connect a MapViewController in a UITab from a UITableViewCell in another UITab?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, mapkit, uitableview

I have an app which has a UITabBarController as root.

Tab1 : Preferences
Tab2 : MapView 
Tab3 : Table List

It basically allows the user to set some preferences and modifies the data presented in the Mapview or Tableview.

But I have to also be able to tap on a location's cell in the tableview (tab3) and return the user to the mapview with that location.

Should I create a new mapview for that?  It seems that connecting back to the original mapview in tab2 would be messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that connecting with the original MapView isnt a good idea. As a usually behaviour when user tap on UITableViewCell you should create a new UIViewController with MapView.